# GET request to front end server and return JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, server, frontend

**UPDATE: 
I have figured it out and solved this question. To do what I was hoping to accomplish here. Do the following:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('server', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getResults: function(blah) {
      var req = {};
      req.blah = blah;

      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'blah',
        params: req
      });
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'server', function($scope, server) {

  $scope.getResults = function() {
    server.getResults($scope.blah)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data;
      }).error(function(data) {
        $scope.results = {
          "Blah": "something"
        };
      });
  };
}]);
```

**Original post:**
My goal is to get the UI to do a GET request to a RESTful server, and obtain a JSON in return. So in my myApp.js, I have:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('server', ['$http', function($http){
    var server = {};

    server.getResults = function(blah) {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP', 
        url: 'blah'
      });
    }

    return server;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, server){
    $scope.results = server.results;
}]);
```

I should clarify that the response I should get from the server is a JSON object that looks like this:

```
var blah = {"Blah": "something"}
```

Comment: What's the question? Only problem I can see is you don't have a `frontend_server.results` property but instead, a `getResults()` function that returns a promise.

Comment: @Phil the frontend server takes in the color and stop selected by the user and passes the information to the backend server for computation, the backend server then returns a string (JSON object) to the front end server which gets passed back to the UI. I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your js should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);

app.factory('frontend_server', ['$http', function($http){    
   return { 
      getResults = function(colors, stops) {
      var results = null;
      var req = {
            colors:colors,
            stops: stops
           }
      return $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'blah',
        params : req
      });
    }

  }
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','frontend_server', function($scope, frontend_server){
    $scope.colors = null;
    $scope.stops = null;
    frontend_server.getResults($scope.colors, $scope.stops).success(function(data){
             $scope.results = = data;

      }).error(function(data){
            $scope.results = = data;
       });;
}]);
```

Comment: ... also, once the `$http` promise resolves, the factory-local `results` variable is re-assigned but `$scope.results` in the controller will still be `null`

Comment: yes, at the beginning $scope.results is null, but $scope.results will get the value lastly!

Comment: No, it won't. I suggest you try it and see.

Comment: could you please create a plunker? i wan't to know how you try it!

Comment: Here's a demo of why your code wouldn't work ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/4ucrlrxKNfWw6HAu8Huw?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104133/discussion-between-vino-dang-and-phil).